# odoo new modules not available

Tags: docker, odoo, add-on

I've installed odoo14 on docker and I'm trying to add more modules but its not working for some reason.

odoo server working fine, I did upload new modules to `/mnt/extra-addons` after that I bashed docker to verify files and they do exist there.
I entered develop mod on odoo, updated app but new modules did not appear.

I originally tried the same steps in localhost and it did work fine but now with cloud its not available.

Any idea how to solve that?
thank you

Comment: Last update, I deleted `/mnt/extra-addons` directory and created new one then upload modules in same path. Two modules out of five were shown in the app list and managed to install, others cannot be found.

Answer (score 2):

on your: `conf/odoo.conf` add: `/mnt/extra-addons`

so:

```
[options]
addons_path = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons, /mnt/extra-addons
```

and on your `__manifest__.py` file add:

```
"installable": True,
"application": True,
"auto_install": False,
```

lastly,

`docker compose restart`

Answer (score 0):

If you have not change the default config, restarting docker container should help, because the python files are cashed in memory, restart will force python to load them from disk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I kept trying to upload multi modules and finally I was able to install the odoo enterprise theme. However for other modules did not appear in the odoo apps. And yes I did stop/restart the container couple times to check if the problem was because of the cash. Note "modules i'm trying to install suppose to support v14 as the description says" I was wonder if I need to rename the file or some thing? andy idea if that required or could help ?

Comment: can you dump one of the `__manifest__.py` files of your modules here?

Comment: code is too long so its posted in separate answer, its for hrm module

Answer (score 0):

For the HRM module it does include multi files, so I'll list two different`__manifest__.py` . First one:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

{
    'name': 'Odoo14 Employee Contracts Types',
    'version': '14.0.1.0.0',
    'category': 'Generic Modules/Human Resources',
    'summary': """
        Contract type in contracts
    """,
    'description': """Odoo14 Employee Contracts Types,Odoo14 Employee, Employee Contracts, Odoo 14""",
    'author': 'Odoo SA,Cybrosys Techno Solutions',
    'company': 'Cybrosys Techno Solutions',
    'maintainer': 'Cybrosys Techno Solutions',
    'website': 'https://www.cybrosys.com',
    'depends': ['hr', 'hr_contract'],
    'data': [
        'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'views/contract_view.xml',
        'data/hr_contract_type_data.xml',
    ],
    'installable': True,
    'images': ['static/description/banner.png'],
    'auto_install': False,
    'application': False,
    'license': 'AGPL-3',
}
```

Second one:

```
{
    'name': 'Open HRMS Branch Transfer',
    'version': '14.0.1.0.0',
    'summary': 'Employee transfer between branches',
    'live_test_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwZ0JpGn-Lw&feature=youtu.be',
    'category': 'Generic Modules/Human Resources',
    'author': 'Cybrosys Techno solutions',
    'maintainer': 'Cybrosys Techno Solutions',
    'company': 'Cybrosys Techno Solutions',
    'website': 'https://www.openhrms.com',
    'depends': ['base',
                'hr',
                'hr_contract',
                'hr_employee_updation'
                ],
    'data': [
        'views/employee_transfer.xml',
        'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'security/branch_security.xml',
    ],
    'images': ['static/description/banner.png'],
    'installable': True,
    'application': True,
    'auto_install': False,
    'license': 'AGPL-3',
}
```

`__manifest__.py` file is not in same directory but I listed the two here cuz they have diffrent result for 'application'